# Show Moore-Penrose Inverse is equivalent to standard inverse if A is invertible and nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra

Show Moore-Penrose Inverse $A^+$=$A^-$ if A is invertible and nonsingular:

I want to check that I doing this proof correctly. Using the 4 properties of the Moore-Penrose Inverse, I believe I show it by:

Property 1) $(AA^+A)=A$

So I can substitue in $A^-$ for $A^+$ and get:

$AA^-A=A$
and
$IA=A$, so it is proven.

Property 2)
$(A^+A)^T=A^+A$
Once again, substitute in $A^-$ and get expression I=I, so it is a true statement.

Is this a correct start to a proof? I have not done proofs in a while.

Comment: If with $A^-$ you denote the inverse of $A$, then from $AA^+AA^-=AA^-=I$ you conclude $AA^+=I$; then $A^-AA^+=A^-I=A^-$, so $A^+=A^-$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically using a strong property of the pseudoinverse. Much less is needed.

If with $A^-$ you denote the inverse of $A$, then from $AA^+AA^-=AA^-=I$ you conclude $AA^+=I$; then $A^-AA^+=A^-I=A^-$, so $A^+=A^-$.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought of doing it this way.